# SQL Server: in-query error catching

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

In my query I have to join tables from db that is not under my control. It is driving me mad as sometimes this db is not accessible (please don't ask me why) and this breaks my query. Fields I'm joining are *not* fundamental for my operations and I want my app to work normally even if these fields are not accessible at a time.

Here's the data structure that I do not own:

```
[DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table1]:
[Field1]
[Field2]

[DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table2]:
[Field1]
[Field2]
[Field3]
```

And here is my table:

```
[DBInMyControl].[dbo].[Table3]:
[Field1]
```

My original query looks something like that:

```
SELECT [Table3].[MyID],
       [ForeignDataQry].[A],
       [ForeignDataQry].[B]
FROM [DBInMyControl].[dbo].[Table3]
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT [Table1].[Field1] AS [MyID],
          [Table1].[Field2] AS [A],
          [SubQry].[Field2] AS [B]
   FROM [DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table1]
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT [Table2].[Field1],
             [Table2].[Field2]
      FROM [DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table2]
      WHERE [Table2].[Field3] = 'Where') AS [SubQry] ON [Table1].[Field1] = [SubQry].[Field1]) AS [ForeignDataQry] ON [Table3].[MyID]=[ForeignDataQry].[MyID]
```

How can i bullet-proof this query so when [ForeignDataQry] generates an error the result would be:

```
[MyID]  [A]  [B]
1       NULL NULL
```

Otherwise

```
[MyID]  [A]  [B]
1       Va1  Val2
```

Is there something that could be done server side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent error when target database in restore mode (sql preparation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630367/prevent-error-when-target-database-in-restore-mode-sql-preparation)

Comment: When another db is not accessible your code cannot be compiled, so the only thing you can do is to try to exec it in another (inner) context, wrapping it in dynamic sql, and if it succeded do nothing, if not, the outer try..catch will catch it and then you exec another code without referencing unaccessible objects

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the expected result of `COUNT`, the three names, and you can check tables beforehand. A minor rewrite can allow this to check for objects other than tables, utilize `EXISTS` if desired, skip or add more checks, etc.:

```
IF 0 = ( -- Specify how many records you expect to come.
    SELECT COUNT(C.[name]) AS [COUNT]
    FROM sys.objects AS O
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = O.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS C ON C.object_id = O.object_id
    WHERE O.[name] = 'tablename'
      AND S.[name] = 'schemaname'
      AND C.[name] = 'columnname'
)
    SELECT 1 AS A -- Do some code.
ELSE
    SELECT 2 AS B -- Do some other code.
```

Comment: And for what reason there will not be this db in sys.databases?

Comment: It can just not to be online, or the user corresponding to the application can be missing: the OP does not precise in what sense the database is not accessible

Comment: @sepupic, is what I'm using deprecated? I just based it on the reference, I'm not much involved with these stuff, and that also plays into me not knowing various inaccessibilities.

Comment: No, I don't say this, I didn't even see that you used sysdatabases instead of sys.databases. I said another thing, if database is just restoring, offline or in single user, it's still present in sys.databases. So your code resolves nothing

Comment: @sepupic, then, should he `TRY EXEC sys.sp_executesql @statement = N'USE MOODY_DB'`, resume query on pass, catch & alternate query on fail? But how to not alternate if resumed query was the failing part? (*without of course using a boolean flag to control*). Also, isn't dynamic SQL a last resort? Do we really have no other options on this?

Comment: If he precise what kind of "unnaccessibility" he means, there can be variants. For example, your code can be modified to check if the db is online.But it cannot be used in case of user missing in that db(to get the error you should try to access an object within the db)

Comment: Let me precise in what sense data might not be accessible... Owner changed table name, owner forgot to add 'select' access rights to the table, owner changed field name

Comment: Sounds different from our initial understanding, which was you having a problem against a database itself, but now we understand it's against tables & columns under a database. Updated answer accordingly. Oh and for both Pawel & @sepupic, "*precise*" can't be a verb, you might be looking for "*clarifies/clarify*".

Comment: @Pawel, previous comment.

Comment: That is what I was saying about: no permissions on the object or another variation: object does not exists. The database is ALWAYS there, so sys.databases  cannot help, the only thing to do is to *try* to execute the query, but any missing object will cause the *compile* error and this cannot be catch in the same context, only in the *outer* context. So, use the dynamic code wrapped in try..catch

Comment: I get you now @sep, I totally forgot about compile issues. But, I'm surprised because my code is somehow compiling, even though what you said is right, that it should not compile: `IF 1 = 0 SELECT * FROM RANDOM_NAME_FDKAFJSKL_284323746819 ELSE SELECT 1 AS A` does not give error, but it should give. What is happening?

Comment: I ended up handling this on the application side in different way than I originally wanted. I will post what I did in an answer. @KtX2SkD Oxford English Dictionary precises definition of the verb 'to precise' as: To make precise or definite; to define precisely or exactly; to particularize. Now rare, but thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the problematic query in dynamic code in order to be able to catch the compilation error (that we cannot catch in the same scope) like this:

```
    begin try
    declare @sql varchar(4000) =

        'SELECT [Table3].[MyID],
               [ForeignDataQry].[A],
               [ForeignDataQry].[B]
        FROM [DBInMyControl].[dbo].[Table3]
        LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT [Table1].[Field1] AS [MyID],
                  [Table1].[Field2] AS [A],
                  [SubQry].[Field2] AS [B]
           FROM [DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table1]
           LEFT JOIN
             (SELECT [Table2].[Field1],
                     [Table2].[Field2]
              FROM [DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table2]
              WHERE [Table2].[Field3] = ''Where'') AS [SubQry] ON [Table1].[Field1] = [SubQry].[Field1]) AS [ForeignDataQry] ON [Table3].[MyID]=[ForeignDataQry].[MyID]'
       exec(@sql)
    end try
    begin catch
        SELECT [Table3].[MyID],
               cast(null as ... )as [A],
               cast(null as ...) as [B]
        FROM [DBInMyControl].[dbo].[Table3]
    end catch
```

Here I use `cast(null as ... )as [A]` to get the same type as `[ForeignDataQry].[A]` has, for example if `[ForeignDataQry].[A]` is int there should be int: `cast(null as int )as [A]`

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this problem in a different way that I originally wanted but anyway:

I created a [Table4] that keeps copy of the records from foreign tables - fields matches [ForeignDataQry] + timestamp. I created procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyForeignData] 
AS

DECLARE @Timestamp datetime
SET @Timestamp = getdate()

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [DBInMyControl].[dbo].[Table4] ([MyID], [A], [B], [Timestamp])
    SELECT [Table1].[Field1] AS [MyID],
          [Table1].[Field2] AS [A],
          [SubQry].[Field2] AS [B],
          @Timestamp
   FROM [DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table1]
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT [Table2].[Field1],
             [Table2].[Field2]
      FROM [DBOutOfControl].[dbo].[Table2]
      WHERE [Table2].[Field3] = 'Where') AS [SubQry] ON [Table1].[Field1] = [SubQry].[Field1]

    DELETE FROM [DBInMyControl].[dbo].[Table4] WHERE [Timestamp] <> @Timestamp
END
```

I will call this every time when I start my app and handle error there and modify my main LEFT JOIN to refer [Table4]